# Sort objects and polymorphism

Tags: c++, sorting, polymorphism

Suppose I have a class A.

And B and C are child of A.

Class A has a generic algorithm for sorting arrays of type A, so that I could use it for B and C without writing again the algorithm for each.

In the algorithm, sometimes I have to swap.
The problem is that I can only see the objects as type A, and if I do:

```
A aux = array[i]
array[i] = array[j]
array[j] = aux
```

I think I have a problem. Because array[i], maybe its of type B, and aux is of type A, so I think I'm losing information.

I'm sure u understand this situation... how can I sort a generic array of objects using a father method algorithm?

Edit: The initial array it's static.

Edit2: So its imposible to have:
A::sort(A array[]);
And do what I want?, cannot swap.

The only way is having an array of references? A* array[]?

Comment: If you have an array of `A`, then the array is not polymorphic. You can't put a `B` or a `C` in there without losing information. You want an array of `A*`, after which the solution should be straightforward.

Comment: There's no polymorphism if you're storing values of type A. There's *object slicing*. Store pointers instead. Then you can virtualize comparison function to sort descendants.

Comment: 'Class A has a generic algorithm for sorting arrays of type A': this class has a lot of responsibility, doesn't it?

Answer (score 9):

Polymorphic objects are referred to by pointers or references (or pointer wrappers). Swapping pointers is sufficient then. Actually, you should be able to use `std::sort` or `std::stable_sort` with a suitable predicate:

```
// 'A' defines 'float getSortKey()'

bool mypred(B* first, B* second) {
   return first->getSortKey() < second->getSortKey();
}

std::vector<B*> them;
std::sort(them.begin,them.end(),mypred);
```

This strategy avoids object slicing.

Comment: I would take out _usually_.  The only way to have polymorphism in C++ is by using a pointer or reference.

Answer (score 0):

@ritmbo, as long as you are not familiar with polymorphism mechanisms, an explanation is needed to fine @Alexander's answer.

Why do you have to change `std::vector<A>` into `std::vector<A*>`?

You want to have a collection of objects of base class, so in order to sort them, you need to move responsibility of object comparison from class `A` to `B` and `C`. To do so, in OOP you use virtual functions. They are bound to an object as a *virtual table*. If you cast `B*` to `A*`, e.g. `A* a = new B;`, the *vtable* of `a` is overwritten by methods from `new B`. But if you cast `B` to `A`, e.g. `A a = B()`, no method pointers are copied to `a`'s *vtable*.

Long story short, you won't **move comparison responsibility** to class `B` and `C` **without using pointers** (or references, but that's more difficult to maintain).

Answer (score 0):

I've got an idea. Your 'polymorphism' tag is quite misleading if you want to store by values. How about **simply overwriting the key value** in `A` class objects, which is used by `A::sort`?

```
struct A
{
    int key;
    A(int _key) : key(_key) {}
    static sort(A array[]); // uses 'key'
};

struct B : public A
{
    B() : A( generate_B_key() ) {}
};

struct C : public A
{
    C() : A( generate_C_key() ) {}
};
```